# NSNotification stop working after showing controller as presentViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsnotifications

I added notification to my UIViewController for catching

```
  - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application:
```

like this

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {

           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:)
                                                 name:APP_RESIGN_ACTIVE_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
```

It is working ok, but if I show other controller like this:

```
[self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view]
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

Notifications stop working.
I remove notifications only in

```
 - (void)viewDidUnload {

     [super viewDidUnload];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:APP_RESIGN_ACTIVE_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
```

But it is not called when I show modal controller.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, I found one place in Base class where I removed notifications.

Comment: I had the same issue: base class removed all notifications... Thanks for sharing your findings - it saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Thank you! Did the same thing.